# How does cropping an image affect camera calibration intrinsics?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I have the following camera matrices for resolution 1600x1300

```
M1 [3x3] =
    [ 1.3964689860209282e+03, 0.,                     8.3190541322575655e+02,
      0.,                     1.3964689860209282e+03, 5.9990987893769318e+02,
      0.,                     0.,                     1.                    ]
```

```
D1 [1x14] =
    [ 8.0832142609575899e-02, -8.0503813500794497e-02, -1.3722038479715831e-03, -6.9032844088890799e-04, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. ]
```

I need to change the resolution to 1280x720, but this resolution is a cropped resolution (not resized). I understand that I have to update  cx & cy. Do distorition coeffients change after cropping operation?

Comment: just try it. Undistort full image, undistort cropped image, compare.

Answer (score 8):

No change, provided you adjust the (cx, cy) coordinates of the principal point to its new location in the cropped image. This is because the focal length does not change, and the [nonlinear distortion model implemented by Opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html) is referenced to the principal point.